# Sending Java date time object to ASP.NET WebApi and storing in SQL Server

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net, datetime

So I have an Android app that has the user choose a date and time. It needs to now send that date and time as part of it's namevaluepairs to a .NET web api that stores data in a SQL Server database table.

What I'm looking for is on android, how to get the java date time object to match the C# DateTime object so that I may save it to the database.
I'm currently doing this (which I deciphered from posts like [this](http://www.pakzilla.com/2007/04/08/inserting-value-in-sql-server%E2%80%99s-datetime-by-javasqltimstamp/):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date(2015, 05, 14);
```

and

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DateAndTime", dateFormat.format(date)));
```

but this produces the following in SQL Server

```
3915-06-14 12:00:00 AM
```

Should I rather be sending the java date and time as a count of milliseconds since 1970 as they do [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2658772/Convert-a-Java-timestamp-to-Csharp-DateTime-object.aspx)?

Comment: what date format .NET webapi accept?

Comment: It's currently accepting the standard C# DateTime as a parameter of the POST method.

Comment: I think you need to debug a little bit and figure out where the Date is going wrong.  Is it screwing up when going from the Java to C#, or when going from C# to SQL?  I think the format you're using ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") should work.  I tried parsing this format using C#'s DateTime.Parse method (which is likely what Web API is doing), and it worked.  I also tried putting that same string into a SQL datetime column, and it also worked.  So I'm not sure where things are going wrong in your case.

Comment: What is your Android date code look like?  How are you formatting it when sending it over?